# How to apply a reduce function with Java threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

If I have a simple program to parallelize counting the number of 1's from a random integer from 0 - 9 for a large number of iterations, how do I reduce the variable counting the 1's (numOnes) using the sum function so that I can be able to use the total sum later on in my program.

This is equivalent to the reduction directive in OpenMP.

```
public void run() {

  long work = total_iterations / threads;
  long numOnes = 0;

  for (long i = 0; i < work; i++) {
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt(9);

    if (randomNum == 1) {
      numOnes += 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Once each thread is done executing, I want to be able to use numOnes containing the aggregate result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you would have to sit down and manage things manually. In other words: assuming that your data is partitioned, you just kick of those 10 threads, and let them do their work.

In the end, you want to **[join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594388/why-we-should-use-join-in-threads)** all those threads; as in: only when all threads "joined"; all of them are done; and you are ready to go forward and process their results.

Alternatively, you would look into more "abstract" things like ExecutorService and Futures; to get away from dealing with "bare metal" threads directly.

Of course that is pretty generic; but well, so is your question.

Comment: I understand that joining waits for all the threads to done, but how specifically would you sum up all the local variable numOnes after joining the threads?

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept. Regarding your comment: as said you could study the ExecutorService. That one allows not only to pass Runnable instances, but also Callable ones. And those can return a value for example! Let me know when you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use streams for this.

```
public class ParallelInts
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int count = new Random().ints( 1_000_000, 0, 10 ).parallel()
              .reduce( 0, (sum, i) -> sum + ((i==1)?1:0) );
      System.out.println( "count = " + count );
   }
}
```