# Why we create new thread and use join() to make parent thread waiting?

Tags: java, multithreading, join

After reading about join method I've some doubt: I think *multithreading* is a way to introduce parallelism in our program and believe some time we need some thread finished before another. But I don't understand why a programmer write something like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(), "t1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(), "t2");

    t1.start();

    t1.join();

    t2.start();

    t2.join();
}
```

whats the advantage of using thread in this example vs below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(), "t1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(), "t2");

    t1.run();//just run the task of thread without start new thread
    t2.run();
}
```

in first example main thread should pause until t1 finished and then start t2 and wait until finished and in second example it happen too.

*Why we create new thread and use join() to make parent thread waiting? why can't use parent thread instead of new thread?*

Comment: calling ***tx.run()*** is not starting any thread, that is the difference!

Comment: In the second case your main method may finished before your thread t1 and t2. that is the difference. In the first case Main method will never finished before threads t1 and t2.

Comment: I know it, my question is why create thread when we need to stop current thread until it's done? why simply didn't use current thread instead new thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both ways, you are not getting benefits.

In your first example, you have two threads and `join()` is not useful.

But assume a scenario where

1. You have multiple threads ( *Main thread, T1, T2, T3 and T4*)
2. Main, *T1,T2* can run in parallel but *T3* should wait for completion of *T4*

In above case, all threads can start in parallel but you join only *T3* and *T4* threads.

Refer to below post for use cases of [join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--):

[Why we should use Join in threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594388/why-we-should-use-join-in-threads)

If you want to explore advanced version of multi-threading, use [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) in place of `join()`

Answer (score 1):

The first way doesn't take profit of multi threading.

We could write it with a single thread, it changes nothing in terms of multi threading :

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(), "t1");
t1.start();
t1.join();

t1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(), "t2");
t1.start();
t1.join();
```

The second way that uses `t1.run();` instead of  `t1.start();`
doesn't start the thread and so these :

```
t1.run();
t2.run();
```

are simple synchronous (blocking) calls to the `Thread` objects.
Only after `t1.run()` is returned, t`2.run()` is invoked.

Comment: I've got my answer: The first way doesn't take profit of multi threading.

I knew difference of run and start, in second code I wanted call run method just like any other method call to perform code inside t1 and t2 run().